# Extract a certain alphanumeric string in cell in Excel or Google Sheets

Tags: excel, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I those string in a Google Sheet:

```
could not find Sample-ID EX617000 in the database!
could not find Sample-ID EX617000 in the database!
could not find Sample-ID EX617001 in the database!
could not find Sample-ID EX617002 in the database!
Sample-ID EX618023 has been processed on 2021-05-23
Sample-ID EX618024 has been processed on 2021-05-22
Sample-ID EX618025 has been processed on 2021-05-22
Sample-ID EX618026 has been processed on 2021-05-22
```

I would like to know how to:

- extract the Sample-ID in one column
- and the date if exist in string

I have tried

```
=MID("EX",1,10) // result in only getting "EX"

=LEFT("EX",10) // result in only getting "EX"
```

Comment: Those are very strange attempts to be honest. I'd suggest looking at the docs for these functions and see how they operate. It seems that "EX" would only occur once in those strings, therefor you could try: `=MID(A1,FIND("EX",A1),8)`. Note: Since GS and Excel may occur to be similar, they are really not. Pick your app of preference and work with that. Remove the tag you don't need.

Answer (score 1):

You could try `FILTERXML()` like-

```
=FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[starts-with(.,'EX')]")
```

[image]

For `google-sheet` you can try-

```
=FILTER(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(A1," ")),LEFT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(A1," ")),2)="EX")
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the solution of Harun24HR you can also try

for the ID's:

```
=arrayformula(if(len(A2:A), iferror(regexextract(A2:A, "(EX\d+)\s")),))
```

and for the dates:

```
=arrayformula(if(len(A2:A), iferror(regexextract(A2:A, "\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}")),))
```

or use a single formula to extract both (id's and dates) into a separate column:

```
=arrayformula(if(len(A2:A), iferror(split(regexreplace(regexreplace(A2:A, "(.*)ID\s",), "[a-z\s!]", "_"), "_"),),))
```

When using the latter, please format the second column of the output as 'date'.

See if that helps?

[image]